# how to get the part of string into a csv file using regular expression/split string in python?

Tags: python, regex, database, string, csv

[this is the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfkRA.png)  I have a column in the database by name build_ID and it has the values as shown below

```
build ID

5.30-420486
5.30-421040
5.30-421225
5.30-420664
```

I am fetching these values on to a csv file. but I want to fetch only

```
420486
421040
421225
420664
```

I want to fetch only these values on to a csv file, I **dont want to fetch like this** 5.30-420486. I want to fetch only the numbers after 5.30- on to a csv file.

Can some one please help me with this.

regards,
darshan

```
def fetch_results():
    query = r"select build_id,pass_percent,original_pass_percent from test_summary where 
    test_suite='%s'"
    test_suite_list=['CI-FIT-Nitro','CI-FIT-Potash','SAT-C7000','SAT-Synergy','SAT-Synergy- 
    gen1','SAT-Synergy-gen2','Scale','Scale-DCS-VET','UPT_C7000','UPT_Synergy']
   
    row_headers, rows = run_query_and_return_results(query,test_suite_list)
    
    if not rows:
       print("Empty rows")
    else:
       print("Rows :" + str(rows))
       return rows
row12 = fetch_results()

for i in row12:
    with open('%s_graph22.csv'%i,'w') as out:
        csv_out=csv.writer(out)
        csv_out.writerow(['build ID','Pass Percentage', 'original_pass_percent'])
        for row in row12[i]:
            csv_out.writerow(row)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NegbW.png)

Comment: `row.split('-')[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

In case of single row - you only need to use:

```
split('-')[1]
```

In the case of your first ex (which shows all in one line), you can use re library as such:

```
import re

string = "5.30-420486 5.30-421040 5.30-421225 5.30-420664"

matches = re.findall(r'\d*\.?\d*-(\d+)', string)
print(matches)
```

output:

```
['420486', '421040', '421225', '420664']
```

Comment: Hi I have a column as shown in the above screen shot, i want the results in the csv file such that it must exclude the 5.30- from the build id coulmn, i need only the remaining part of the number.  Like that i have many csv files which are having same column headers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code works (hard to tell without the data and the rest of it), you just need to change this line:

```
csv_out.writerow(row)
```

To something like:

```
csv_out.writerow([row[0][5:], *row[1:]])
```

Or, if you just want everything after the position of the first dash and would like to use regex (although there's simpler ways for a match like that), `import regex` at the start and:

```
csv_out.writerow([re.match('^.*?-(.*)$', row[0]).group(1), *row[1:]])
```

Assuming every line has at least one dash.

A bit of explanation: if you have a list (e.g. `xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]`) and you do somthing like `[xs[0]+1, *x[1:]]`, you get a new list that has the first element of the list `x[0]` and some operation performed on it like `+1`, followed by the rest of the list `x[1:]`, which is every element in the list starting at the one at index `1`. The asterisk `*` is there to 'unpack' the list, to make sure the new list has the elements inside the list, not the list itself.

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print([xs[0]+6, *xs[1:]])  # prints [7, 2, 3, 4]
print([xs[0]+6, xs[1:]])  # prints [7, [2, 3, 4]]
```

The regular expression `'^.*?-(.*)$'` just says to match everything between the start `^` and end `$` of a string, starting with the smallest number of characters up to the first dash `.*?-` and followed by everything else captured in a group `(.*)`. That's why `.group(1)` then gets you the part of the string you are after.

You could probably do without the `^` and `$`, but I put them in there to be explicit. If the string only contains `'123-456789'`, it would be fine without. If for example the string has quotes like `'"123-456789"'`, you'd want those quotes instead of the start and end markers.

Comment: Hi I have a column as shown in the above screen shot, i want the results in the csv file such that it must exclude the 5.30- from the build id coulmn, i need only the remaining part of the number.  Like that i have many csv files which are having same column headers

Comment: if you clink on the link which i mentioned above , you can get to see the results of csv file

Comment: I'm sorry, but your image only shows the same columns again and it appears you haven't even read the answer.